# Hide folders in root repository browser (subversion) for certain users

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've a subversion server running on a Linux machine (Debian).
Multiple users access the server via TortoiseSVN on Windows 7/8/10
I've multiple groups, with different access policy. Some users can add new folders to the root.

But I've now an problem. I've a new user.
He's accessing the repository via the repository-browser.
But he's not allowed to see some folders in the root. How can I configure the server that that user can log in via the root folder, but don't see that folders. 
I do not prefer to put every folder in the authz file with no access, because some users can add folders (and I've to update the authz file every time).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is that possible on a subversion server?
Must authorization not only be done by the Apache/Subversion configuration files?

Answer (score -1):

If those 'some folders' and the users accessing them are few in numbers, you can user group to restrict the new user.

1. add a new group, groupX
2. add groupX as supplementary group to all allowed users
3. change the permission of 'some folder' to 070.

basically, it looks like this

- #groupadd groupX
- #usermode -aG groupX alloweduser1 # do the same for other users.
- #chmod 070 'folder1' #do the same for all folders.